# Undefined class constant 'SQLSRV_ENCODING_SYSTEM'

Tags: sql-server, laravel, laravel-5, sqlsrv

when trying to run php artisan migrate on laravel i'm getting the error

```
In database.php line 79:
Undefined class constant 'SQLSRV_ENCODING_SYSTEM'
```

i have the sql drivers etc installed but unsure how to solve this problem

database.php file

```
'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'options' => [PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_SYSTEM => false], // Used for MSSQL encoding
    ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanations:**

`PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_SYSTEM` is `PDO_SQLSRV Driver Constant`, not an option name. You should use `PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING => PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_SYSTEM` in options. Have in mind, that this option is Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server specific driver attribute (one of `PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING` and `PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY`).

```
<?php

...
'sqlsrv' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'options' => [PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING => PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_SYSTEM]
],

...
?>
```

**Notes:**

Documentation: [Microsoft SQL Server Functions (PDO_SQLSRV)](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) and [Constants (Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/constants-microsoft-drivers-for-php-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).